# What is the original reason JSON used `null` and not `undefined` to represent missing values?

Tags: javascript, history, json

In Javascript, there seems to be or have been an idea that `undefined` represents a missing primitive OR object value, while `null` represents just a missing object value.

See, for example, this section in [Speaking JS](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch08.html#undefined_null).

The use of `null` in JSON, however, does not seem to obey this principle. If the value of my key is missing, JSON represents this situation as "the key is present with the value `null`". But the value could have been either a primitive or an object, so wouldn't it be more correct to those semantics to use `undefined` in this case?

I know JSON has no particular reason to be faithful to this aspect of Javascript now, but I'm curious about the considerations that went into this decision at the time that it was made.

Answer (score 5):

`undefined` means that you got the name of the variable/field wrong, or that for some reason that variable/field was not set (maybe the program did not go through the code path that sets it?). `null`, however, means that you got the name right, and that the code that was supposed to put a value in there did put a value - but that value legitimately means "there is nothing here".

In other words - `dog.tail === undefined` means that the concept of dogs having tails is meaningless. `dog.tail === null` means **this** particular dog has no tail.

Comment: Are you talking about the JS semantics here? I don't think the builtin JS functions consistently use `undefined` and `null` in this manner -- for example, suppose I am searching for the dog's tail in an array of tails using `Array.find`, and it is not present. `Array.find` will return `undefined`, but that does not mean the concept is meaningless.

Comment: You asked about JSON - a serialization format meant to used by other languages. And in these other languages, `null` means "this thing is empty" while `undefined` means "what are you even talking about?" and actually throws an exception when you try to access that field. That JS is returning `undefined` instead of throwing an exception is an anomaly.

Comment: The problem with nailing down the meaning of null is that so many people have used it to mean so many things.

Comment: Thanks @IdanArye, just trying to understand. Are you saying that `null` was chosen for JSON because the token "null" is more commonly used in other languages than the token "undefined"?

Comment: It's less about the _tokens_ `null` and `undefined` and more about the _concepts_ represented by these tokens. Most languages have `null` or `none` or `nil` or some similar token/value. If the language is statically typed, maybe not all types can receive it, or maybe you need to specially mark the variables/types that can receive it. It's different, but always means the same thing - there could have been a value there, but there isn't.

Comment: The token `undefined`, as you said, is not that common - the only mainstream language I can think of that has it is JS. Other languages don't have a similar token with a different name - unless you count the empty string in shell languages. Every language, however, still has the **concept** of undefined - usually in the form of errors. In statically typed languages it could be compilation errors. Dynamically typed languages can throw exceptions, and statically typed languages do that too when you access a nonexisting item in a dictionary/array.

Comment: So, for these languages to accurately parse a JSON with `undefined` in it, they should throw an error. Or omit that item. And this is not very useful, since the JSON dumper could just have omitted that value itself.